# How can increase the width of the frame little bit beyond the margin?

Tags: frame, customize

```
\documentclass[letter,10.5pt]{article}
\usepackage[head=0pt,bottom=0.6in,top=0.8in, left=0.5in,right=0.5in, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{\Large\color{white}Resume}
\fancyhead[L]{\Large\color{white}Dmitry Yakovlev}



\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[c]{}
\fancyfoot[l]{\thepage { \color{gray} | P a g e}}
\fancyfoot[r]{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

%%%%%%%%%%% pdflatex %%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%% xelatex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
% \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{navyblue}{RGB}{31, 78, 120}
% line spacing
\linespread{1.0}

% section reformatting
%\titleformat{\section}{\color{black} \large}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}]
%\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
%\newcommand{\sectitle}[1]{
%    \vspace{1.5ex}
 %   \section{#1}
 %   \vspace{-3ex}
 %   \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.7pt}
  %  \vspace{-4ex}
%}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large}{}{0pt}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\color{navyblue}%
\AtPageUpperLeft{\rule[-20mm]{\paperwidth}{20mm}}%
}
\newmdenv[
  backgroundcolor=gray!5,
  skipabove=8pt,
  skipbelow=0pt,
]{reminder}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\topskip=20pt
\parskip=10pt
%\parindent=0pt
%\baselineskip=15pt


\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor={linkcolour!90}, linkcolor={linkcolour!90}}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\lhead{\color{white} M: +64 000 00000}
\chead{\Large\color{white} \textbf{DMITRY YAKOVLEV}}
\rhead{\color{white} E: gjguygugyg@gmail.com}

\section{\color{navyblue} SUMMARY OF QUALIFICATIONS}
Results-driven, customer-focused, and innovative professional with years of work experience in diverse software development roles. Highly skilled in JavaScript, React, Node.js and associated technologies. Hands-on experience in front-end and back-end development of web-based applications and advanced development methodologies, as well as design and development of automation systems. My proven capabilities in self-management, get-up-and-go attitude, and ability to understand complex coding with ease make me an ideal candidate to fit the position of software engineer, and I am confident that I will be a valuable asset to your organisation.

\begin{reminder}
\begin{center}
    \underline{\color{navyblue}\Large Core Competencies/Areas of Expertise}
\end{center}
\centering{Software Engineering • Front-end and Back-end Development • DevOps • CI/CD • Technical Support and Troubleshooting }\\
Programming Skills • Analytical Skills • Project Management • Root-cause Analysis\\
Creativity • Attention to Details • Leadership and Teamwork Abilities • Decision Making • Critical Thinking • Effective Communication
\end{reminder}

\end{document}
```

[I want to increase the width of the frame as shown in this image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the right an left margins using the keywords `leftmargin=...` and `rightmargin= ...` in the definition of the new environment of `mdframed`.

To keep the same text width use `innerleftmargin = ...` and `innerrightmargin = ...`

[image: a]

```
\newmdenv[
backgroundcolor=gray!5,
skipabove=8pt,
skipbelow=0pt,
leftmargin=-20pt,% <<<
rightmargin=-20pt, % <<<<
innerleftmargin = 20pt, % <<<<<
innerrightmargin = 20pt %<<<<
]{reminder}
```